# MongoDb entry porint error after installing php driver

Tags: php, mongodb

I tried to install mongodb. After placing php_mongodb.dll in php/ext folder in xampp folder I am getting

> The procedure entry point php_var_unserialize_init could not be
>   located in the dynamic link library php7ts.dll

error while I restart xampp server in Windows 7 (64 bit).

My php version is 7.
Thread safety is enabled
My compiler is MSVC14 and Architecture is x86.

I tried to place php7ts.dll,but still i am getting same error.

Comment: Hi Vijai, have you solved this issue?. I am also getting same error for an other .dll file

Comment: no i can't able to solve this issue.i am going to linux ubuntu server.